# per user language settings on Wii U

Tags: wii-u

I recently bought a Wii U and intend to spend a lot of time playing games. I prefer to play these games in their original languages (usually English).

My kid is 2.5 years old and eventually he'll want to pick up a controller as well. He doesn't speak English, as we live in the Netherlands and he's barely speaking Dutch at his age.

Is it possible to configure the Wii U so that one user account is set to use the English language, and another is set to Dutch?

Comment: I'm fairly certain there isn't a user language setting, only a system language setting in the Wii U menu. So if there is a solution to the above problem, it's not in the configuration options given to users by Nintendo.